# Drupal 6 to 7 Migration: unlimited length field using a textfield widget issue while migrating fields

Tags: migrations

I'm migrating a drupal6 site to drupal7. I had disabled all contributed moduels and ran database update which went smooth. I have enabled CCK and migrate modules, but now on the content migrate, I'm getting this for several fields - Invalid field/widget combination: The field 'field_names' in the bundle 'bundle_names' is an unlimited length field using a textfield widget, not allowed in D7. Below is snapshot of one such field:

[image]

This comment on [Migrating D6 Content Construction Kit (CCK) to D7 Fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1144136#comment-7714209) page says to give maximum lengths <= 255 before running Migrate Content. How do I do this now?

Comment: I tried few solutions that are provided in [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1117028) like changing datatypes in the database, but none worked.